# How to zoom camera in iOS devices when we are in video call using WEBRTC

Tags: ios, webrtc

I want to zoom the camera in iOS devices when we are in videocall using WebRTC Framework...

```
   NSError *error = nil;
    if ([captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error])
    {
        captureDevice.videoZoomFactor = 1.0 + pinchRecognizer.scale * pinchZoomScaleFactor;
        [captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to change the WebRtc library code to access the native camera in Ios.At present there are no Api's available to do Camera zoom in Webrtc ios.

Comment: With triggering a function over a socket you can call native functions (via Cordova for example) and use the zoom.